# Can't access returned object - resource service

Tags: angularjs

This is my first Angular app so I'm sure there's something obvious I'm doing wrong, but I've Googled and searched this site without any luck.

I'm using the $resource service to make an AJAX call to get some JSON from a weather API. The function below retrieves it (via the weatherService's function) and I'm able to successfully log the returned object to the screen ([console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNoNQ.jpg)). When I try to access any of the object's properties (ex. info.cnt), logging it returns *undefined*. Can't figure out why this is. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var info = weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city);
    console.log(info);
}
```

My custom weather service:

```
weather.service('weatherService', function($resource){

    this.city = 'Chicago, IL';

    this.getForecast = function(location) {

        this.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

        this.weatherResult = this.weatherAPI.get({ q: this.city, cnt: 5, appid: 'e92f550a676a12835520519a5a2aef4b' });

        return this.weatherResult;
    }

});
```

Comment: Do this please.. `weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city).then(function (response) { console.log(response.data.cnt); }, function (response) { // error });`

Comment: Tried that, got a TypeError: _angular.min.js:118 TypeError: weatherService.getForecast(...).then is not a function_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get call will be executed async. So, your service should be like:

```
weather.service('weatherService', function($resource){

    this.city = 'Chicago, IL';

    this.getForecast = function(location) {

        this.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

        return this.weatherAPI.get({ q: this.city, cnt: 5, appid: 'e92f550a676a12835520519a5a2aef4b' });

    }

});
```

and you should consume like:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city, function(response) { 
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE RETURN 
    });
};
```

You can see that we are passing a callback, that will be called when the HTTP request is completed.

If you want to be more advance, you can, and should, use promises. It would became:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
   weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city).$promise.then(function(response){
        //SUCCESS
    }).catch(function(error){
        //ERROR
    });
};
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), to see some more awesome functionalities.

**So, why you still see same data in the screen:**

The thing is that the $resource service mimics a sync operation. Given the data-binding of angular, if you tied your return to the $scope, the response eventually will be completed, and during the $digest cycle, the framework will revisit your variable and see that it has some data. But, like I said, it is due to the data-binding, you can't, as you saw, access immediately your data.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'm still a little confused as to how my original `info` variable can ostensibly store the object but then doesn't have the contents accessible. I know it's because it's asynchronous and I successfully tested it (my original code) successfully with `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(info.cnt); }, 3000);` Still a little perplexing though.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot more sense now. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

$resource service is returning an promise which you need to resolve like this

```
weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city).then (function(data){;
        console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need a resolve function like this;

```
$scope.submit = function() {
   weatherService.getForecast(weatherService.city).then(function(res){
     // success handler
      console.log(res);
   },function(error) {
     // error handler
   });
}
```